# Changing the value of a session variable in RSpec/Capybara/Selenium

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, session, rspec, capybara

I'm starting to write feature specs for a Rails application using Rspec with Capybara and Selenium to drive the browser.

While executing one of the specs I want to change the value of a session variable. Eg: I want to set session[:user_id]=123 so that I can test features in my application without having to go via the login screen every time.

When using Capybara with the default rack_test driver, the rack_session_access gem works for accessing the session. But it doesn't seem to work when using the Selenium driver.

And yes, this question has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6547603/2518285), but no satisfactory answer has been given.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the value of a session variable in specs while testing in Ruby on rails.(with capybara and selenium)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547603/changing-the-value-of-a-session-variable-in-specs-while-testing-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: Yes, I know it's a duplicate ... I even linked my question to the earlier question. But I am not happy with the accepted answer to the older question, which really isn't an answer.

Answer (score -1):

Short answer, you don't. Longer answer, that's completely against the point of feature tests which are meant to be end to end.

That being said, if for performance reasons you want to short circuit the login, most authentication libraries provide a test mode that will allow you to do that - devise via the Warden TestHelpers for instance

Comment: Logging in is a feature like any other feature. If I run a suite of 100 feature tests for my app, I want logging in to be tested once, not 100 times. I also want to be able to run any one of the 100 tests in isolation.

Comment: @BrettDonald Which, as I stated, is why most auth frameworks provide a test mode.  There is no access to modify session variables in feature tests because you shouldn't be directly modifying them. You set up DB state and then run your app unmodified with that data.  If you don't want to use the test mode of your auth framework then you can visit a page in the site , add a correctly signed cookie to the browser, then revisit the page - but that's more complicated than using the test mode or just logging in.  Just because  you don't like the answer doesn't mean it's not the correct answer.

Comment: Sometimes setting things up through the user interface or the database is just too complicated due to external dependencies. You may consider explaining how the test mode of an auth framework might work around the lack of access to the session so that technique can be used for cases where no test mode is available.

Comment: Thanks, stackoverflow, for not allowing me to change my vote 